# Evicting cache of a specific tenant

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, ehcache

I have a schema-based multitenant application that uses Ehcache. Sometimes I need to evict the cache of a specific tenant/schema instead of whole application. Is there a way to achive this? Currently I use `Cache#evictAllRegions` and this is not what I want.

Ehcache Version: 3.9.9

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with Hibernate. Maybe your cache provide might have an option to implement something like that. The `CacheKeyImplementation` has a tenant identifier, so you might be able to remove all entries where the key object has a certain property value, but this is not something that the Hibernate integration provides out of the box.